# Methods to Accelerate Read From a Large Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I try to log every thing in SQL, so think to add a table named `log` and add every things in it, the `log` table is:

- `ID` UNIQUEIDENTIFIER --  PK
- `LogDate` DATETIME PK
- `IP` NVARCHAR
- `Action` NVARCHAR
- `Info` XML
- `UniqueID` BIGINT

I log every things like: login, check permission, see pages, access object and .. to this table

Then I figured also need Some **Log-Restore**  Implementations, So some log records are restorable, some of them not, The `Log` table have about 8 millions Records, but the restorable records are about 200 thousands, So every time we need to restore, need to select on 8 millions, then I decide to add new Table and Add restorable logs 
to this new table: `log_restore`:

- `ID` UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
- `LogDate` DATETIME
- `IP` NVARCHAR
- `Action` NVARCHAR
- `Info` XML
- `UniqueID` BIGINT  -- PK

OK when I need To log every thing is fine.

But when I need to see logs: The procedure get all records from `log` table and merge(union) them with `log_restore` table.

So I need to accelerate this procedure **with no effect on insert (means do not slower that)**, this is my ideas:

1. When Add record to `log_restore` Add it to `log` table also (So in select no need to union)
2. Create view with this select command
3. Add Simple DataType Columns instead of XML
4. Add Clustered PK on simple DataType Column Like `BIGINT`

What are your ideas? any suggestion?

Comment: Can you share your SQL please?

Answer (score 6):

In general, one should try using as little space as possible; it greatly helps reducing disk seeks when executing a query. And comparing smaller datatypes always require less time!

The following tunings can be made on the columns:

- use non-nullable columns (decreases storage space, diminishes the number of tests)
- store `LogDate` in the form of a timestamp (UNSIGNED INT, 4 bytes) instead of DATETIME (8 bytes)
- `IP` address shouldn't be stored as a NVARCHAR; if you are storing IPv4 adresses, 4 bytes would be enough (BINARY(4)). IPv6 support requires 18 bytes (VARBINARY(16)). Meanwhile, NVARCHAR would require 30 bytes for IPv4, and 78 bytes for IPv6... (search the web for inet_ntoa, inet_aton, inet_ntop, inet_pton to learn how to switch between binary and string representation of the adresses)
- instead of storing similar data in two separate tables, add a `Restorable` flag column of type BIT indicating whether a log entry can or cannot be restored
- your idea about the `Info` column is right: it would be better to use a TEXT or NTEXT data type
- instead of using a NVARCHAR type for `Action`, you could consider having an `Action` table containing all the possible actions (assuming they are in finite number), and referencing them with an integer foreign key (the smaller the int, the better)

Index optimization is very important too. Use an index on multiple columns if your query tests multiple column at the same time. For example, if you select all the restorable rows corresponding to a specific IP over a certain range of time, this would greatly enhance the speed of the query:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_IndexName ON log (Restorable ASC, IP ASC, LogDate ASC)
```

If you need to retrieve all the restorable rows from an IP adress corresponding to a specific action, over a given range of time, the index should be chosen as such:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_IndexName ON log (IP ASC, Action ASC, LogDate ASC)
```

Etc.

To be honest, I would actually need to see your full SQL query in order to do proper optimization...

Answer (score 3):

Options for table enhancements:

1. Add a `Restorable bit null` column and create a filtered index on it.
2. 'XML' data type is a LOB data type and is stored outside the row. If you are not using any of [XML data type methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx), then you do not need it. It does hamper your performance a lot. Add and `XML_code varchar () null` column and copy all data from your `XML` column.

Choose the length of the column so to keep maximum row size (total max size of all columns) less than 8Kb. `Varchar (MAX)` column may be stored in row if row fits 8kb. So if you have significant number of short XMLs, then `VARCHAR (MAX)` can help.

3. If you are not working with Unicode data, then change all `NVARCHAR` to `VARCHAR` columns
4. Use a `UNION  ALL` with a `Where` cluse to filter duplicates instead of just `UNION`
5. `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column does not help you here. If two records cannot have same `datetime` (or maybe `datetime2) value, then it can you unique ID on its own. Alternatively consider changint`ID`column to`int`as you order by`int` in sensible manner.

Re your thoughts: number (4) will not help. Create indexes on both tables, that follow Where clauses and JOIN columns.

Make several iterations: Simplify data types - Check performance. Create index(es) - Check again. And so on. There should be a balance between minimizing space used and usability. You may want to keep some data in text, rather encoding to int or binary.

Use Profiler or Tuning adviser to determine bottlenecks and improvement opportunities.

Comment: Note: `Varchar(MAX)` is a LOB data-type too.  Using that instead of `XML` datatype won't help anything and may make somethings a lot worse.

Comment: Are you sure your index/statistics are current ? Has the SP being recompiled lately ? Any fragmentation on your index? I noticed you are using UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  as the PK. This is a GUID which is not sequential and this may be causing performance issues. Have you tried profiling the sp?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Have a look at this link: http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsPerfBlog/archive/2008/04/16/ntext-vs-nvarcharmax-in-sql-2005.aspx. It seems that SQL Server stores VARCHAR(MAX) in row, if it fits 8kb.

Comment: @stoleg: Yes, the same is also true for XML columns and for all of the "new" large-object types. This includes the types added in SQL Server 2005 or later: `Varchar(MAX), NVarchar(MAX), Varbinary(MAX), XML`, etc. I do not think that the old/deprecated LOBs (`Text, NText, Image`) were grandfathered for this new handling.

Comment: Note: what John Conwell doesn't mention his article is that this can be controlled somewhat through the use of `sp_tableoption`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make a wild guess that the property that identifies whether something is "restorable" or not is the `Action` column. If that is the case, then partition the table by that column and forget about the `log_restore` table.

MSDN - [Partitioned Table and Index Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Partitioning by column with small number of distinct values is not a good practice. Partitioning is a management tool in first place and may result in poorer performance.

Comment: @Stoleg. Not really sure where you read that. Partitioning is used to create virtual sub-tables so that you only process that subset of data you need. It is beneficial specially on how Saeid plan to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to be worried is the memory of the machine, How much the server has? then you should compare with your database size, or maybe just the size of the table you are working on. If the memory is to low compared with the size of the table, then you have to add more memory to the server. Thats the first thing you have do.

[A Sysadmin’s Guide to Microsoft SQL Server Memory](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/)